# Button form submission not submitting NULL

Tags: php, html, forms

I am working with a fairly straight forward form yet for some reason it is not submitting NULL results and instead submits them as empty results.

```
<div class="span6"> 
    <form action="" method="POST">                                       
        <div class="block-fluid without-head">                        
            <div class="toolbar clearfix">
                <div class="right">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-small btn-warning tip" data-original-title="Submit Aritcle">
                            <span class="icon-ok icon-white"></span>
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-small btn-danger tip" data-original-title="Delete Article">
                            <span class="icon-remove icon-white"></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="left">
                    <div style="font-size: 11pt; font-family: -webkit-body; font-weight: bolder;">Article Exchange Request</div>
                </div>
            </div>                        

            <div class="row-form clearfix">
                <div class="span3">Title</div>
                <div class="span9"><input type="text" name="title" value="" placeholder="main subject title"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="row-form clearfix">
                <div class="span3">First Sentence</div>
                <div class="span9"><input type="text" name="s1" value="" placeholder="Sentence with max of 200 characters"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="row-form clearfix">
                <div class="span3">Second Sentence</div>
                <div class="span9"><input type="text" name="s2" value="" placeholder="Optional sentence with max of 200 characters"></div>
            </div>                                                

            <div class="row-form clearfix">
                <div class="span3">Third Sentence</div>
                <div class="span9"><input type="text" name="s3" value="" placeholder="Optional Sentence with max of 200 characters"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="row-form clearfix">
                <div class="span3">Website Url</div>
                <div class="span9"><input type="text" name="link" value="" placeholder="Url to be included in articles"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="row-form clearfix">
                <div class="span3">Website Url Title</div>
                <div class="span9"><input type="text" name="link_text" value="" placeholder="Url text to be included in articles limit 150 characters"></div> 
            </div>

            <div class="row-form clearfix">
                <div class="span3">Credit Offer</div>
                <div class="span9"><input type="text" name="cost_value" value="" placeholder="Example: 100"></div>
            </div>
        </div>                    
    </form>
</div>
```

The problem is someone can just come along and submit the form without entering any data at all, and it still submits, and adds empty results to every column in the database. Meaning no NULL values are being set in the database.

My form processing

```
<?

if (isset($_POST[cost_value])) {
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT credits from member_credits WHERE username = :username");
    $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    $count = $row[credits];
    if ($count > $_POST[cost_value]) {
        $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO article_requests (title, s1, s2, s3, link, link_text, offer, username) VALUES (:title, :s1, :s2, :s3, :link, :link_text, :offer, :username)');
        $stmt->bindValue(':title', $_POST[title]);
        $stmt->bindValue(':s1', $_POST[s1]);
        $stmt->bindValue(':s2', $_POST[s2]);
        $stmt->bindValue(':s3', $_POST[s3]);
        $stmt->bindValue(':link', $_POST[link]);
        $stmt->bindValue(':link_text', $_POST[link_text]);
        $stmt->bindValue(':offer', $_POST[cost_value]);
        $stmt->bindValue(':username', $username);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
?>
```

What I expect to happen on submission is if no value is entered in the form it should be set to NULL... that would mean if no $_POST[cost_value] was set, the form wouldn't submit. As it stands now, it is ALWAYS seeing $_POST[cost_value] as being set - sometimes to a value such as $_POST[cost_value] = '100'; and other times $_POST[cost_value] = ''; but in both cases, the form will submit. Equally I have the database set so that only the values of s2 and s3 should be able to be null, however when everything is submitting empty instead of null, thats mostly useless.

What exactly am I missing? Why will it not say $_POST[cost_value] = NULL; if the user has not input a value? Why is it submitting ''?? I have a feeling its going to be something basic I am overlooking, I just don't see it....

**UPDATE FOR CLARITY**

I know there are a number of ways to fix this. I can use if then tests, I can use temporary variables, I can check for the value itself is something other than ''. I know WHAT the work arounds are. I don't understand WHY they are needed. Why is it I make forms every day of the week using if isset, and everyday that works. If a form has no values input from the user, the form won't submit because an if isset returns false. So why is it on this particular form it is submitting '' instead of saying !isset don't process.

Comment: Granted I can use ternary operators to solve this I suppose, I have just never encountered this before. I make forms all the time and usually if someone submits a form with no data, the form doesn't process. Thats why (I thought) it was fairly standard to use if(isset) on POST form processing.

Comment: I wouldnt suggest setting NULL on the POST. I would have that set in the database so that if there is no values input during the rows creation then it will auto be set to NULL instead of a string text of "NULL"

Comment: @Levi thats just it. the database DOES have columns set to be NULL, but when submitting an empty value, an empty value will get set, not NULL. THAT is why I am confused.

Comment: `$_POST[title]` (and all other `$_POST`-params) should have quotes: `$_POST['title']`. As it is, it should throw a notice: _"Use of undefined constant"_.

Comment: Posting an empty input field doesn't equal null, it is what you declared `value=""` = empty string (and is therefore set).

Comment: I can add single double or no quotes, and all three reproduce the same results. The only real difference as far as I know is if you log warnings, php will give a warning about undefined if something is undefined without quotes.

Comment: I have also tried both with and without value="" on the inputs

Comment: You should always use quotes. Doing it without quotes might still work (except from the notices) but that's because PHP's error handler will try it with quotes if the constant doesn't exist. Coding in a way that forces the error handler to fix your code is lazy and really bad practice.

Comment: I am updating the question because obviously people are not understanding me question.

Comment: @Fred-ii- my update changed nothing about my original question, but it may change the answers I am getting as I am not looking for a solution, I am looking for the cause.

Comment: because, isset and empty are two different animals and you have `value=""` which most likely accounts as "something" and does not equal NULL; that's my best explanation without having to test your code Bruce. check if empty and don't use empty values for the inputs.

Comment: Well I have tried it without the value="" on the inputs with no change. But yes I suppose in this instance the solution is to test the value, and set them properly to NULL if they are empty. I just wish I knew why this was happening, as over time this form is going to have close to 100 fields... perhaps mpre, which means I have to test each and every field and set NULL if empty.

Comment: You also have `<button type="submit"` and `<button type="button"`. The former will always be considered as "not empty" here, which is something to be said about the answer given below, where the first line of their answer reads as `if ( !empty($_POST))` and that will fail based on your submit button, which the other "button", does nothing really and only works with JS/Ajax if being used. Again, and from my deleted comments, use a ternary operator with a default as NULL and using a submit button. As to the "why they are needed", that's because it avoids getting errors back by MySQL.

Comment: Sorry Bruce, but I guess I am not grasping the question. I really wish you find the solution/answer you're looking for, *cheers*. Wish I could have been of more help, good luck.

Comment: Check if isset($_POST[cost_value]) && !empty($_POST[cost_value] ). That should do the trick.

Comment: Unfortunately its not that simple. I have to check each and every value, otherwise values are blank not NULL. So for example if someone fills out all the fields except s2, s2 will not be saved in the database as NULL, it will be saved as empty result. I have to check first to that the value is infact something other than '', if its '' I have to set it to NULL

Answer (score 1):

// Assign a var to the post.

```
$DIRTY_Var = $_POST['varinputname'];
```

// ensure the var is cleaned (no funny business when submitting)

```
$CLEAN_Var = filter_var($DIRTY_Var,` FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

// check if the var is empty, or has value. If empty it will set the var to null;

```
if (!$CLEAN_Var) { return $CLEAN_Var = null; }

    // validate input
    $valid = true;

    // insert data
    if ($valid) {
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO Table ("
                                ."ColumnNames"
                            .")"
            ."VALUES("
            ."?"
            .")";
        $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array($CLEAN_Var));
        // Once INSERT is completed, we will redirect.
        header("Location:" 'link.php'); exit; 
    }
```

Comment: `if ( !empty($_POST)) {` will fail with `<button type="submit">` since it's considered as a POST input/array. So, each time the submit is pressed, it's going to be considered as "not empty".

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
   If(isset($_POST['cost_value'])  &&    !empty($_POST['cost_value']){
```

// your code
}

Comment: should it not be If(isset($_POST['cost_value'])  &&    !empty($_POST['cost_value']){ ?

Comment: checking if isset and empty? -1